# Jquery code not working in JSP page

Tags: jquery

I have piece of jquery code for animation which is working in plain HTML page but not working in JSP page here is mine code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/color/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $('#totalCost1').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffe000' }, 250).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'}, 750);
    $('#coop1').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffe000' }, 250).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'}, 750);
    $('#outOfPocket1').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffe000' }, 250).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'}, 750);
</script>
```

Comment: *Not working* isn't very helpful. Not working how? Error? Unexpected results?

Comment: Nine months and *24 other questions*. With respect, you really should be able to format code by now. @alex fixed the first version for you, but your recent edit breaks it again. See the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question edit area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Answer (score 2):

your js code must be in `<script></script>` tags

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/color/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript">
 $('#totalCost1').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffe000' }, 250).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'}, 750);
        $('#coop1').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffe000' }, 250).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'}, 750);
        $('#outOfPocket1').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffe000' }, 250).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'}, 750);</script>
```

Comment: You can't have `src` **and** content in the same `script` element like that. You have to have separate `script` elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script (This isn't just academic, it actually won't work on some major browsers.) (Other than that, assuming the script thing isn't just an error in the question, good catch.)

Comment: Apparently, it was just an error in the question, which the OP has now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The below should work. 
If you have JQuery script at:

> /MyApp/WebContent/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js

You need to refer in any JSP / FTL as following:
if JSP is at :

> /MyApp/WebContent/pages/user/listUsers.jsp

In JSP refer stylesheet as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/styles/myStyle.css"/>
```

In JSP refer JQuery as :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```