# jQuery working on HTML, not in JSP

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have a virtual keyboard package (obtained from the http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/) that I am trying to get working on my website.  Following their documentation, I was able to get it working on an HTML page, with the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 
 <link href="css/keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $('#keyboard').keyboard();
  });
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
  var tbRow = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < tfrow; i++) {
   tbRow[i] = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
   tbRow[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
   };
   tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#d4e3e5';
   };
  }
 };
</script>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body viewsource="no">
 <div id="wrap">
  <input id="keyboard" type="text">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when the exact same content is in a file with a .jsp extension (that I encode using eclipse / spring) on a tomcat server, the jQuery doesn't work.  The only jQuery function that I have been able to run on the jsp page is to pop up an alert.

I looked at an earlier questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867220/jquery-not-working-in-jsp-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869337/jquery-code-not-working-in-jsp-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241789/jquery-not-loading-on-jsp-page) that I thought was similar, but didn't find anything that helped.

Any help is appreciated by this newbie!

---

Update: Including JSP code:

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
 prefix="sec"%>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 
 <link href="css/keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $('#keyboard').keyboard();
  });
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
  var tbRow = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < tfrow; i++) {
   tbRow[i] = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
   tbRow[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
   };
   tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#d4e3e5';
   };
  }
 };
</script>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body viewsource="no">
 <div id="wrap">
  <input id="keyboard" type="text">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where have you placed the `jsp` file . Have you placed it inside `WEB-INF` ?

Comment: check the output HTML and see if the jQuery code is there. The JSP at the end is creating an HTML page to be rendered so nothing special is required to be done.

Comment: @SanKrish I have placed the jsp file in web-inf/jsp

Comment: @dawez The output html page has the jquery code.  If I view the source of the code, and save it as .html, it starts working again.

Comment: @user4192616 you would have to post the JSP page otherwise it's hard to debug.

Comment: @dawez... included the JSP code in my update.

Comment: why are you using `jquery` twice i.e. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 `

Comment: @ApulGupta I didn't have to... those were part of my attempts to try different versions of jquery to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got it working by adding the following under the script:

```
    $('#username').focus();
```

and the naming the input field username as follows:

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <input id="keyboard" name='username' type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Is this working ? it does not make any sense to me. You are looking for the element with the id of **username** while you have an element with input id as **keyboard**. Why is this working then ?